# How to refresh a list view item without scrolling it off screen

Tags: android, listview

I'm using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. I'm just curious if I can refresh a list view item without scrolling it off screen when call that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` will automatically call `getView()` for every row currently at least partially visible on the screen.
You don't have to scroll anything.

Comment: I only see items getting refreshed if they are COMPLETELY OFF the screen.

Comment: Show your adapter implementation

Comment: Okay, I have posted it

Answer (score 0):

From the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())

> notifyDataSetChanged(): Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

So, in other words , whenever you call that method, is being called the [getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) method and refresh the content of your changed slots.

Comment: Thank you, but that is not what I am observing.